# Laravel pagination links are not working in View. Getting error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I am using laravel default pagination in controller

```
public function deals(){
    $deals = Deal::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(1);
    return view('deals', compact('deals'));
}
```

In view, I am getting pagination links like this

```
 <div class="text-center">
    {{$deals->links() }}
 </div>
```

I am getting this error

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

I have tried following but nothing working.

1. Used render instead of links.
2. used sortBy instead of orderBy

   **When I dd $deals->links() in the controller it is working but in view, I am getting error.**

Comment: I tried the same code and it is working fine at my end

Comment: Yes, it is very unfortunate. I have pagination on many other pages and all are working fine. But facing this issue only on this page.